# IIS7.5 Register PHP as .Net Extension

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7.5

Is it possible to register .php as a .net extension in IIS 7.5? This used to be possible in IIS6 with ISAPI extensions

I'm converting a web application from php to .net and there are a couple of urls that were heavily used in the old site. I would basically like to keep the file name and have it do a redirect to its aspx equivalent without having to install PHP on the server.

Thanks,
Duane

Comment: `I'm converting a web application from php to .net` well only part of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldnt get IIS to read a PHP file, I was able to hand the PHP off to a 404 handler. In the 404 handler I check the requested page's url and forward the request to the appropriate aspx version of the page.